# Most efficient way to load and process large images in JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx, pixel

I just need some guidance and I can't find another question that anwers this. The answer even doesn't have to be JavaFx-specifi, I guess.

I 'd like to load and manipulate fairly large Images/Pixel-Arrays in a JavaFX-Application.

Right now I have just a simple approach: A simple Stackpane which holds a Canvas object, loaded into a ScrollPane.

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
Canvas = new Canvas(4000,6000);

stackPane.getChildren().add(canvas);
scrollPane.setContent(stackPane);
root.setCenter(scrollPane);
```

At A certain Canvassize it is not possible to create a Canvas object and I get a few exceptions. What if I had bigger dimensions in my mind?

Does the total size of the canvas affect the performance or just the detail view in the the scrollpane?

Comment: From your question it is not clear why you use a `Canvas` while talking about images. To my mind in JavaFX this means `Image` and `ImageView`. Please clarify.

Comment: Someone told me Canvas has better performance when working with pixel arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At A certain Canvassize it is not possible to create a Canvas object and I get a few exceptions.

By default, JavaFX nodes are rendered by graphics hardware as textures.  Different graphics hardware has different limits in the maximum size a single texture may be.  Normally, this texture size limit is an order of 2 and common maximums for various graphics hardware might be 8192x8192 or 16384x16384.  For compatibility reasons, it is probably best to assume a maximum texture size of 8192x8192 or even 4096x4096 if you wanted to be very conservative.

> What if I had bigger dimensions in my mind?

Use multiple nodes in a tiling algorithm.  For example create a 32768x32768 canvas using an 8x8 array consisting of 64 4096x4096 individual canvas nodes.  You will need to write the logic for handling this yourself, there is no existing library out there that will do that for you as far as I know.  For extremely large dimensions, e.g. hundreds of thousands or millions of pixels across, then a virtualized control such as a [GridView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) may be of assistance.

> Someone told me Canvas has better performance when working with pixel arrays

I doubt that a canvas would have better performance characteristics than a [WritableImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) backed by a [PixelWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html) and [PixelReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getPixelReader--), as canvas needs to service a wider and more complex array of features and functions.  That said, for most applications, users are pretty unlikely to note any substantial difference between the performance of a canvas and a WritableImage and you should probably choose between the two based upon the best functional fit for your application.

As an aside, one performance tip when working with pixel level manipulation of image data, is to choose an appropriate [PixelFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelFormat.Type.html) that is natively used by your graphics hardware, as that reduces the amount of data copying and transformations of pixel data that the underlying graphics rendering system needs to do.   For more information in understanding this performance tip, refer to the related Oracle JavaFX forum thread: [Canvas performance](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2436712).

Answer (score 1):

Using a canvas here is probably not such a good idea because a canvas does not provide a PixelReader. The only way you can get at the pixels is to make a snapshot. With an image you have both a PixelReader and a PixelWriter. I doubt that any serious image manipulation programm would work without being able to manipulate individual pixesl in both directions.